# Error while inserting Date in MSSql

Tags: sql-server, jsp, date

[image]
this is my table format

```
ArrayList<String> dates = (ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("dates");

 for(int i =0;i<7;i++)
 {
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.sql.Date d= new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse(dates.get(i)).getTime());

PreparedStatement pst1=mc.conn.prepareStatement("insert into dbo.timesheet_details      values(?,?,?)");


    pst1.setInt(1, newtmId);
    pst1.setInt(2, 36);
    pst1.setDate(3,d);

    pst1.executeUpdate();
 }
```

this is my array list dates.

```
 dates = [2014-09-23, 2014-09-24, 2014-09-25, 2014-09-26, 2014-09-27, 2014-09-28, 2014-09-29]
```

Error is ...

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash:
>   date is incompatible with text

Please help me how to convert this array list in correct date format..

Comment: What is the table-definition of `timesheet_details`? Could you add that to your post please?

Comment: From looking at your code, I don't really spot a mistake that would result in the SQLServerException. What I do notice is that you create a PreparedStatement in each iteration of your loop, which is a mistake. Prepare your statement once, and use the PreparedStatement in your loop as you do now (by calling `executeUpdate`). Afterwards don't forget to clean up your statement by closing it.

Comment: Could you please post the complete stack trace for the exception?

Comment: actually i don't have problem with sql statement. problem is insertion of date.

Comment: You are preparing a statement in each iteration of your loop, while you only need to do this once. This is a performance bottleneck that results in more communication with the RDBMS than what is necessary. On top of that you are not properly closing your statement which leads to unneccessary memory consumption (or leaks depending on your code). A prepared statement is "prepared" so you can use it multiple times, so that you not have to create one for each call.

Comment: even if i am not using loop, problem in insertion of date only. problem in conversion of string date to date

Comment: The other columns in table dbo.timesheet_details are either NULLable or have a suitable DEFAULT?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify all the column names you are trying to insert. Try the following INSERT statement and see if you still have a problem

```
INSERT INTO dbo.timesheet_details(det_id,emp_id,period)VALUES(?,?,?);
```

Comment: Could you post as much of the Exception Trace as possible? Also, are the other columns NULLable or do they have suitable defaults? Very little information to work with.

Comment: other fields are not nullable. i am not getting any others. problem with date only..this is the only error i am getting.....            com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with text